# search specific numbers within text inside brackets with php

Tags: php, json

my question is simple, 
I want to echo a specific numbers with dots inside text that I'm  taking from a specific webpage... currently I'm printing the following

{"VERSION":"2.00.000"} 
        but i want only to print this 2.00.000 my line of code is this

```
 $url  = "http://smthng.com/blabla";
     $site = file_get_contents($url); 
     echo " the version of the app is ".'<br/><br/>';
     echo " $site ";
```

how can I do that? 
any help would be really appreciated
thank you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this came a json string response, then just plainly use `json_decode()`.

```
$url  = "http://smthng.com/blabla";
$site = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
echo " the version of the app is ".'<br/><br/>';
echo $site->VERSION;
```

Comment: awesome!!! Ghost and Simon Brahan u rule guys thank you!!for the fastest quality answers ever!!!

Answer (score 0):

this if you get always this type of response `{"VERSION":"2.00.000"}` , it is a json, so

```
$string = '{"VERSION":"2.00.000"}'; //or how you get it
$decodedArray = json_decode($string,true);
echo $decodedArray['VERSION'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks like it is encoded as JSON. To geet just the version number, try this:

```
$url  = 'http://smthng.com/blabla';
$site = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
echo 'the version of the app is<br/><br/>';
echo $site->VERSION;
```